# make the input value change without clicking button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make it give me the value that I put in at "summe:" when changing the numbers without actually clicking the calc button how do I do that? I tried with `onchange` but I cant figure out how to do it

```js
const btncalc = document.querySelector('.calcit');
const summetext = document.querySelector('.summe');
const backend = document.querySelector('.backenduser');

backend.addEventListener('onchange', function() {
  var backendanzahl = document.getElementsByClassName("backenduser")[0].value;

  var appanzahl = document.getElementsByClassName("appuser")[0].value;
  var mytext = "Anzahl der Summe:" + (+backendanzahl * 35 + +appanzahl * 7.5);
  summetext.textContent = mytext;
});
```

```html
App-Benutzer: <input type="number" placeholder="1-100" min="0" max="100" oninput="this.value = this.value > 100 ? 100 : Math.abs(this.value)" class='appuser'></input><br> Backendbenutzer: <input type="number" placeholder="1-15" min="1" max="15" oninput="this.value = this.value > 15 ? 15 : Math.abs(this.value)"
  class='backenduser'></input><br>
<button class='calcit'>Berechnen</button><br>
<span class='summe'>0.00</span><br>
```

Comment: Not `onchange` - just `change` or maybe `input` (they work slightly differently). Also maybe use `querySelector` in the callback instead of `getElementsByClassName` since you're familiar with how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll` to get references to both fields. And then `forEach` to apply event listener to both. Also as any points out the event you are looking for is `change`.

```js
const btncalc = document.querySelector('.calcit');
const summetext = document.querySelector('.summe');
const backend = document.querySelector('.backenduser');
const updateOnChange = document.querySelectorAll('.update-on-change');

updateOnChange.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('change', function() {
     var backendanzahl = document.getElementsByClassName("backenduser")[0].value;

     var appanzahl = document.getElementsByClassName("appuser")[0].value;
     var mytext = "Anzahl der Summe:" + (+backendanzahl * 35 + +appanzahl * 7.5);
     summetext.textContent = mytext;
  })
});
```

```html
App-Benutzer: <input type="number" placeholder="1-100" min="0" max="100" oninput="this.value = this.value > 100 ? 100 : Math.abs(this.value)" class='appuser update-on-change'></input><br> Backendbenutzer: <input type="number" placeholder="1-15" min="1" max="15" oninput="this.value = this.value > 15 ? 15 : Math.abs(this.value)"
  class='backenduser update-on-change'></input><br>
<button class='calcit'>Berechnen</button><br>
<span class='summe'>0.00</span><br>
```

Comment: so i use querySelectorAll and put it in a foreach loop so i dont have to do it twice?

Comment: Yes I used a new class on each of the input fields, then queried that with query selector all. But that returns a NodeList and not a single element reference. Nodelists have a forEach method on them which allows you to loop over the members. Within that list you can add the event listener that updates your output on `change` event

Answer (score 0):

Add an `input` handler. Change event only triggers when the element has lost focus.

```
element.addEventListener('input', function (evt) {
    //do your stuff here
});
```

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent)